# Passing JSON from AngularJS to Springboot RestController is not working

Tags: json, angularjs, spring-restcontroller

I am facing a problem with one of the project that I work. Here is the scenario.

I have Angular Springboot project, where from a HTML page, data has to be sent to Springboot Controller (restController) and does the processing.
When I send a single String as input to an endpoint, it works, but when I have to send a JSON, it does not work.

Here is the sample code.

AnnotationController.js

```
$scope.postExample = function() {
    var annotationjson = {
        acctNo: $scope.tradeAnnotationDto.acctNo,
        tradeComment: $scope.tradeAnnotationDto.tradeComment
    };
    AnnotationService.postExample(annotationjson).then(function() {
    }, function(reason) {
        console.log("error occured");
    }, function(value) {
        console.log("no callback");
    });
}
```

AnnotationService.js

```
service.postExample = function(annotationjson) {
    alert("Post Example Click Value is " + annotationjson.acctNo + "  " + annotationjson.tradeComment); -- I see the data here.
    return $http.post(“/annotatetrade/postExample“, annotationjson);
}
```

AnnotationController.java (restcontroller)

```
@RequestMapping(value= "annotatetrade/postExample", method= RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
public void postExample(@RequestParam TradeAnnotationRequest request){
    System.out.println("Post Example account " + request.getAcctNo());
    System.out.println("Post Example comment " + request.getTradeComment());
}
```

TradeAnnotationRequest.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ApiModel(value="TradeAnnotationRequest")
public class TradeAnnotationRequest {
    String acctNo ;
    String tradeComment ;
}
```

With @RequestParam, this is what I get.
2021-11-17 13:28:55.996  WARN 24572 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required TradeAnnotationRequest parameter 'request' is not present
2021-11-17 13:29:14.447  WARN 24572 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required TradeAnnotationRequest parameter 'request' is not present

With @RequestBody, I get nulls.
For some reason, JSON data is not passed. Can anyone please help?
I went through lots of posts.

---

I have some progress. However I am still getting data null in my restcontroller.
Following changes are made

```
        service.postExample = function(medicoRicercato) {
            alert("Post Example Click Value is " + medicoRicercato.acctNo + "  " + medicoRicercato.tradeComment);
            return $http({
                url: CONSTANTS.postExample,
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                method: "POST",
                data: {medicoRicercato},
                dataType: 'json'
            });

            //return $http.post(CONSTANTS.postExample, medicoRicercato);
        }
```

and in my restController

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/postExample", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json",
            headers = "content-type=application/json")
    public void postExample(@RequestBody TradeAnnotationRequest request){

        System.out.println("Before Request");
        System.out.println(request);
        System.out.println("Post Example ac " + request.getAcctNo());
        System.out.println("Post Example co " + request.getTradeComment());
    }
```

added following dependency in my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>

        </dependency>
```

However I am still getting null. Could anyone who knows please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your postExample (the json body) as:

```
{
        "acctNo": $scope.tradeAnnotationDto.acctNo,
        "tradeComment": $scope.tradeAnnotationDto.tradeComment
}
```

Pay attention the quotation mark.

Comment: Thanks Shay.
In added quotes as below
```
{
                "acctNo": $scope.tradeAnnotationDto.acctNo,
                "tradeComment": $scope.tradeAnnotationDto.tradeComment
};
```
and my RestController has
```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postExample", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json",
            headers = "content-type=application/json")
public void postExample(@RequestBody TradeAnnotationRequest request){
```

Still the values are null as 
TradeAnnotationRequest(acctNo=null, tradeComment=null)
When I checked the values in service.js, it is there.